# Sum Of Values In a list C# (.Net 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-2.0

I have a list i want to get the sum of this list & want to show it in a label

my list is

```
   List<double> Amount = new List<double>();
```

& it's filled up with integer values i need to get the sum of it.

i don't really know how to add values. tried some properties like compute, sum but it gives syntax error since it do not work with this.

here's how i am getting values in it

```
 double sales = double.Parse(split_values[1]);
                    listBox2.Items.Add(sales);
                    Amount.Add(sales);
```

& i need to show the output in a label

I also need to get top 3 values from this list but till yet i was unable to do so.
**.net Framework is 2.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;            

var amount = new List<double>() { 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 5.5 };
            var sum = amount.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            var highest3 = amount.OrderByDescending(a => a).Take(3);

            var i = 1;
            foreach (var d in highest3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is position {1}",d,i);
                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Edit: Framework 2

```
var amount = new List<double>() { 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 5.5 };
            var sum = 0.0d;
            foreach (var d in amount)
            {
                sum += d;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);

            amount.Sort();
            amount.Reverse();

            lbl_first.Text = amount[0].ToString();
            lbl_second.Text = amount[1].ToString();
            lbl_third.Text = amount[2].ToString();

            var i = 1;
            foreach (var d in amount)
            {
                if (i > 3)
                    break;

                Console.WriteLine("{0} is position {1}",d,i);
                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: it's 2.0 so we can't use Sum etc. because it require Linq & Linq can be used in 4.0 :(

Comment: it's working but how can i print top 3 values in labels. plz :/ sorry i am Noooooooooob

Comment: Do you have the labels defined @CodingNoob? If so, you can do `label1.text = d.ToString();` in the `foreach` loop

Comment: my lables are like lbl_first & lbl_second etc.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer...so, you don't need anymore help?  I have edited the answer with your lables...you can ignore the console parts.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use LINQ try something like this:

```
List<double> Amount = new List<double>();

var sum = 0.0;

Amount.ForEach(x => sum += x);
```

Comment: it worked :D Thanks Dude. can you tell me a bit please about getting top 3 values from list plz @Alessandro D'Andria

Answer (score 1):

Sum of the list can be achieved in many ways, here is the simplest, `Amount.Sum();` (Linq is required).

Concerning the label request, i haven't fully understood you.

Comment: i think we can't use linq in windows form. i am not able to add reference

Comment: for linq project must be vs4.0 or above.

Comment: oh i think i forgot to mention i am using 2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

List<double> Amount = new List<double>() {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};  
Console.WriteLine(Amount.Sum()); //10

var top3 = Amount.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(3); // 4.0, 3.0, 2.0
```

Comment: i believe Sum needs some assembly reference that is not present in my windows form

Comment: @CodingNoob `using System.Linq;`

Comment: i forgot to mention i am using .Net Framework 2.0 & for linq it requires 4.0

Answer (score 1):

```
double sales = Double.parseDouble(split_values[1]);//it's convert to double
Amount.add(sales);//value is added
```